# How to return dynamic array to Python using ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

Hi i want to return a dynamic array to python from c funtion.

this is my c funtion

```
extern "C" uint32_t* function(){
uint32_t *u_id;
  uint32_t size = common::size();
  u_id = (uint32_t*)malloc( size*sizeof(uint32_t) );
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    u_id[i]
  }
  return u_id;
```

I follow the example and write these python codes. However, if i write in this way, the result is limited to size of 10. How can I adapt it to dynamic size?

```
import ctypes

mylib = ctypes.CDLL('./library.so')
mylib.function.restype = ctypes.uint*10
res = mylib.function()
```

Comment: Try passing the size as a parameter.

Comment: Could you please detail how to do this? ```size = common::size();``` is written in C. How can i achieve that?

Comment: What is the definition of `common::size()`?

Comment: ```common::size()``` is an API which returns the size.

Comment: You definitely need a way to return the size of the allocated pointer, or Python will have no way to know the returned size. You can try to use `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.uint)` for the return type.

Comment: Also, if it's possible, I suggest using pybind11 for C++/Python bindings. It's way nicer than ctypes.